# Generating two independent random number sequences (C++)

Tags: c++, random

I'd like to be able to do something like this (obviously not valid C++):

```
rng1 = srand(x)
rng2 = srand(y)

//rng1 and rng2 give me two separate sequences of random numbers
//based on the srand seed
rng1.rand()
rng2.rand()
```

Is there any way to do something like this in C++? For example in Java I can create two java.util.Random objects with the seeds I want.  It seems there is only a single global random number generator in C++. I'm sure there are libraries that provide this functionality, but anyway to do it with just C++?

Comment: Since the numbers returned by `rand` are (pseudo-)random, why do you need more than one generator?  Getting 2n numbers from one random number generator should give similar results to getting n numbers from each of two random number generators.

Comment: @James: Consider a queuing simulation with one source of randomness controlling the arrival of new tasks, and another source of randomness influencing the time to complete each task.  One might want to repeat each experiment multiple times, replicating the "task arrival" scenario, but with different "task completion" statistics, and that would require having multiple RNGs that can be seeded independently.

Comment: @Jim:  I agree that it could be used for that.  I'd think it better to feed the "random" data in manually then rather than relying on the PRNG.

Comment: @Jim: It is indeed for simulating a queuing system. 
@James: The simulation has 10^6 events. I'm not going to feed the data in manually :)

Comment: @James: It is quite common to use a deterministically-seeded PRNG as a reproducible, nominally infinite, "stream" of randomness. A manually-prepared stream has no advantages that I can think of.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [rand_r](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand_r).

Answer (score 7):

In TR1 (and C++0x), you could use the `tr1/random` header. It should be built-in for modern C++ compilers (at least for [g++](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a01192.html) and [MSVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982398.aspx)).

```
#include <tr1/random>
// use #include <random> on MSVC
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    std::tr1::mt19937 m1 (1234);  // <-- seed x
    std::tr1::mt19937 m2 (5678);  // <-- seed y

    std::tr1::uniform_int<int> distr(0, 100);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++ i) {
        std::cout << distr(m1) << "," << distr(m2) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use [Boost.Random](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_random.html).

[More technical documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_random/reference.html#boost_random.reference.generators) here.

Answer (score 2):

I just want to point out, that using different seeds may not give you **statistically** independent random sequences. mt19937 is an exception. Two mt19937 objects initialized with different seeds will give you more or less (depending whom you ask) statistically independent sequences with very high probability (there is a small chance that the sequences will overlap). Java's standard RNG is notoriously bad. There are plenty of implementations of mt19937 for Java, which should be preferred over the stock RNG.

Comment: What does it mean "statistically" i.r.v.?

Answer (score 0):

as @James McNellis said, I can't imagine why do you would do that, and what pros you will get. Describe what effect you would like to achieve.

Comment: This would be better left as a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, the following generators interfere with each other. I need two independent generators for a task and need to reconstruct the streams. I haven't dug into the code but the std::tr1 and C++11 generators seem to share states in common. Adding m2 below changes what m1 will deliver.

```
std::tr1::mt19937 m1 (1234);  // <-- seed x
std::tr1::mt19937 m2 (5678);  // <-- seed y
```

I had to build my own to ensure independence.